# Calculate freq by group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as below. I want to group the data by recid and add column count1 and count2 such that all the values are counted in both col1 and col2. So example count1 in row 1 will be 2 because 10 occurs 2 times in both the columns and Freqcol1 will then be 2/4

```
ID col1 col2 recid
 1   10   12 abc_12
 2   10   15 abc_12
 3   10   10 def_34
Desired output:

ID col1 col2 recid count1 count2 Freqcol1 Freqcol2
 1   10   12 abc_12     2     1     0.5     1
 2   10   15 abc_12     2     1     0.5     1
 3   10   10 def_34     2     2     0.5     0.5
```

My code from [Calculate the occurance of a number in two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77687492/calculate-the-occurance-of-a-number-in-two-columns/77687823#77687823)

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>%
  mutate(count = n(), .by = value) %>%
  mutate(freq = count / n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(value, count, freq))
```

Comment: If you are looking for a `dplyr`-specific answer, I urge you to add the [tag:dplyr] tag and/or explicitly state this in your question. Many infer it from the code in the question (which is generally fine), in which case the tag is certainly appropriate.

Comment: I see `10` four times in that frame, why is `count1` 2? Is it just that it is in both columns, so `count*` will only contain values `1` and `2`?

Comment: count1 is 2 beacuse now the data is grouped by recid. So for recid value 10 occurs only 2 times in both col1 and col2.

Comment: okay, if you're doing it by group, is there a reason you aren't grouping by `recid`, such as `group_by(recid)` or `mutate(..., .by=recid)`?

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` method, no pivoting, dynamic to the number of `col#` columns (in case that's useful):

```r
library(dplyr)
quux %>%
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("col"),
           ~ colSums(sapply(.x, `==`, c(col1, col2))),
           .names = "{sub('col', 'count', .col)}"),
    across(starts_with("count"), 
           ~ .x / sum(.x), 
           .names = "{sub('count', 'freq', .col)}"),
    .by = recid
  )
#   ID col1 col2  recid count1 count2 freq1 freq2
# 1  1   10   12 abc_12      2      1   0.5   0.5
# 2  2   10   15 abc_12      2      1   0.5   0.5
# 3  3   10   10 def_34      2      2   1.0   1.0
```

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, col1 = c(10L, 10L, 10L), col2 = c(12L, 15L, 10L), recid = c("abc_12", "abc_12", "def_34")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(col1:col2) %>% 
  mutate(count=n(), .by=c(recid, value)) %>%
  mutate(freq = 1/count, .by=c(recid, name)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from=name, values_from=c(value, count, freq))
```

which returns

```
# A tibble: 3 × 8
     ID recid  value_col1 value_col2 count_col1 count_col2 freq_col1 freq_col2
  <int> <chr>       <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1 abc_12         10         12          2          1       0.5       1  
2     2 abc_12         10         15          2          1       0.5       1  
3     3 def_34         10         10          2          2       0.5       0.5
```

for the sample data

```
df <- read.table(text="ID col1 col2 recid
1   10   12 abc_12
2   10   15 abc_12
3   10   10 def_34", header=T)
```

This produces slightly different column names by you can rename them in a later step if required.

Comment: i run into the following error Values from `count`, `freq` and `value` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
• Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
• Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates.
• Use the following dplyr code to identify duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(recid) %>%
  mutate(
    count1 = sum(col1 == col1[1]),  # Count occurrences of col1 value within group
    count2 = sum(col2 == col2[1]),  # Count occurrences of col2 value within group
    Freqcol1 = count1 / (count1 + count2),  # Calculate frequency for col1
    Freqcol2 = count2 / (count1 + count2)  # Calculate frequency for col2
  ) %>%
  ungroup()  # Release grouping
A tibble: 3 × 8
     ID  col1  col2 recid  count1 count2 Freqcol1 Freqcol2
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <int>  <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1    10    12 abc_12      2      1    0.667    0.333
2     2    10    15 abc_12      2      1    0.667    0.333
3     3    10    10 def_34      1      1    0.5      0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply however frequencies look wrong. Freqcol1 in row1 should be 1/2 = 0.5